# Почему при нажатии миниатюры выводится миниатюра , fullsize изображение

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function closeModal() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

function showModal() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('ModalOpen');
  modal.style.display = 'block';

  ;
  (function gallery() {
    var leftArrow = document.getElementById('leftArrow'),
      rightArrow = document.getElementById('rightArrow'),
      initImgNumber = 1;
    maxImgNum = 14;

    leftArrow.addEventListener('click', moveBackvard);
    rightArrow.addEventListener('click', moveForvard);

    function moveBackvard() {
      var image = document.getElementById('mainImage');
      initImgNumber--;
      if (initImgNumber == 0) {
        initImgNumber = maxImgNum
      };
      image.setAttribute('src', 'images/gallery/big/' + initImgNumber + '.jpg');
    };

    function moveForvard() {
      var image = document.getElementById('mainImage');
      initImgNumber++;
      if (initImgNumber > maxImgNum) {
        initImgNumber = 1
      };
      image.setAttribute('src', 'images/gallery/big/' + initImgNumber + '.jpg');
    };

  })();

  function changeImage(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
      document.getElementById("mainImage").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");

    }
  }
```

```css
.Window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Window:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.Window>div {
  width: 1030px;
  height: 640px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 74px -50px;
  background-size: 925px 640px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px;
  background-color: white;
}

.share {
  position: absolute;
  right-12px;
  top: 52px;
  left: 992px;
}

.fbshare {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: 509px;
  left: 992px;
}

.twshare {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: 546px;
  left: 992px;
}

a {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.leftcol {
  width: 200px;
  height: 590px;
  float: left;
  background: url("images/lcolb.jpg") no-repeat;
}

.rigcol {
  width: 45px;
  height: 590px;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 1030px;
  height: 50px;
}

.learn {
  position: relative;
  top: -58px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0066cc;
  float: right;
}

.learnT {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.learn:hover {
  background: #3399FF;
}

.learn:hover a {
  color: #fff
}

hr {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 462px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  border: 0;
}

.Tfind {
  margin-top: 380px;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.Thorizont {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 211px;
  color: white;
}

.hr2 {
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
}

.hr3 {
  width: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 226px;
  left: 5px;
}

.img1 {
  margin-left: 86px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.img1 {
  margin-left: 46px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.img2 {
  margin-top: 89px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.bgmain {
  width: 785px;
  height: 443px;
  margin-top: 107px;
}

.button1 {
  width: 732px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button2 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button3 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 135px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 22px;
}

.nav {
  font: 12pt;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  width: 190px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.6s linear;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  transform: scaleY(1.2);
}

.img3 {
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#GalleryWrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 164px;
}

#gallery {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
}

.arrowleft {
  position: relative;
  top: 205px;
  left: 36px;
  width: 5%;
  float: left;
}

.arrowright {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 205px;
  width: 5%;
  float: right;
}

.arrowleft img {
  width: 100%;
}

.arrowright img {
  width: 100%;
}

.arrowleft img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 95%;
}

.arrowleft img:active {
  width: 85%;
}

.arrowright img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 95%;
}

.arrowright img:active {
  width: 85%;
}

#thumbs {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 440px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 150px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  background-color: dimgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topgal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.topgal img {
  border: 2px solid dimgray;
  margin: 0px 1px 17px!important;
  width: 99px;
  height: 59px;
}

.bottomgal {
  margin-top: 75px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#ModalOpen" title="">
  <button type="button" class="button1" id="modal_close" onclick="showModal();">
  <img src="images/ban.jpg"> 
  </button>
</a>
<div id="ModalOpen" class="Window">
  <div class="content">

    <div id="GalleryWrapper">
      <div class="arrowleft"><img src="images/left.jpg" id="leftArrow"></img>
      </div>
      <div id="gallery"><img src="images/gallery/big/1.jpg" id="mainImage"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="arrowright"><img src="images/right.jpg" id="rightArrow"></img>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbs" onclick="changeImage(event)">
      <div class="topgal">
        <img src="images/gallery/small/1.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/2.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/3.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/4.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/5.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/6.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/7.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/8.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/9.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/10.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/11.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/12.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/13.jpg" />
        <img src="images/gallery/small/14.jpg" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="leftcol">
      <img class="img1" src="images/ps4.jpg">
      <img class="img2" src="images/logo.jpg">
      <div class="tabs">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#tab1" class="active">Video</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#tab2">Horizon Zero Dawn</a>
            </br>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#tab3">Through Aloy's Eyes</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-1">

      </div>
      <div id="tab-2">

      </div>
      <div id="tab-3">

      </div>

      <img src="images/esrb.jpg" class="img3" />

    </div>
    <div class="rigcol">
      <button type="button" class="button2" id="modal_close" onclick="closeModal();">
     <img src="images/x.jpg">
    </button>
      <button type="button" class="button3">
     <img src="images/share.jpg">
    </button>
      <hr>
      <p class="Tfind"> Find <br/>US ON</p>
      </hr>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="fbshare">
        <img src="images/fb.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.twitter.com" class="twshare">
        <img src="images/twit.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <img src="images/i.jpg" class="img1">
      <hr class="hr2">
      <p class="Thorizont">Click on Horizon Zero Dawn to see the next era of mankind</p>
      <div class="learn">
        <p class="learnT"><a href="#learnmore">Learn More <strong> > </strong></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не рабочий пример

Comment: @Tachkin тут важен не пример , а код и логика написанния которая у меня не пашет

Comment: именно пример. Если хотите, что бы люди разобрались и помогли, то будьте добры добавить минимально воспроизводимый пример, который можно посмотреть, понять суть проблемы, исправить и протестировать.